# ESP32S v1.1 NodeMcu vs ESP32 DevKitV1

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, esp32, espressif

I have two different ESP32 development boards labelled "ESP32S v1.1 NODEMCU" (A) and "ESP32 DEVKITV1" (B).  From what I can tell they have the same major components, but their pins and general layout are quite different. I assume they are both knock-offs.

[image: ESP32S v1.1 NODEMCU]

[image: ESP32 DEVKITV1]

When uploading from the Arduino IDE, both read the same revision number and features:

```
Chip is ESP32-D0WDQ6 (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
```

From what I can tell NodeMcu has something to do with the firmware for the ESP8266 ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NodeMCU))?  Also, it seems my ESP32S NodeMcu board doesn't have the standard pin layout for ESP32 boards.

What exactly is this NodeMcu board and what are the differences between the two?

Comment: there's lots of wroom modules, all vary slightly in pinout, serial chip, component selection, etc; but they all do the same basic thing as far as arduino is concerned. I try to find ones with 36+ pins and pin labels on both sides of the board, and that are cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DevKit](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/devkits/esp32-devkitc) is a development board by ESP32 manufacturer [Espressif](https://www.espressif.com/) to demonstrate ESP32 usage and to support prototyping.

The NodeMcu is a board by [NodeMcu](https://www.nodemcu.com/index_en.html) intended for the NodeMcu Lua language firmware.

There is no standard pinout. The labels on the DevKit are io pin numbers of the MCU.

You can use both development boards with the ESP32 "Arduino boards support package".

Comment: I wrote to Espressif asking about the ESP32 DEVKITV1 and they said they don't manufacture it. It appears to be made by this company: https://www.doit.am/#/mozu